# ¿Cómo agregar el valor del input a un if?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

me encuentro haciendo ejercicios de algoritmos para luego pasarlos a código.
En este ejemplo VSC me muestra que "domingo" y "matutino" no están definidos, pero no logro comprender el porqué debo de definirlos, si ello será escrito en el input.
Gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La comparación debes hacer con un string: if dia=="domingo", tal y como lo tienes estás comparando con una variable que no has definido.

Comment: Agreaga el código y el enunciado como texto por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que ya que hablamos de comparación de texto y no de variables o números debes colocar matutino o domingo entre comillas ""

Answer (score 1):

```
Objeto1 = input("¿Sí o no? (1 = Sí, 2 = No,)")
Objeto_1 = int(Objeto1)
if Objeto_1 = 1:
   print("Dijiste Sí")
else if Objeto_1 = 2:
   print("Dijiste No")
```

Esa es la solución. Espero haber ayudado. Tienes que crear otra variable (preferiblemente parecida) y darle el mismo valor que al anterior. Después pones la segunda variable al if y como es igual al primero, te dará el resultado correcto.